# Subquery returns more rows

Tags: mysql

I have trouble with this mysql code,

mysql schema

```
att (`e_id`, `state`, `date`, `time`)

(1, '0', '2019-05-09', '9:39:50'),
(1, '1', '2019-05-09', '15:39:5'),
(2, '0', '2019-05-09', '8:39:50'),
(2, '1', '2019-05-09', '16:39:5');
```

and my code return this error (Subquery returns more than 1 row)

```
SELECT att.e_id, att.date, 
(SELECT time FROM att WHERE e_id = att.e_id AND state = '0' ) as 'enter_time', 
(SELECT time FROM att WHERE e_id = att.e_id AND state = '1' ) as 'end_time' 
from att GROUP BY e_id, date
```

Comment: Add limit 1 to the end of the subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in your subquery MySQL doesn't know what value of `e_id` you mean in the `WHERE` clause and so it picks the one from `att`, which then matches for **all** rows in `att` which have the appropriate `state` value. You need to tell MySQL to use the version from the table copy by qualifying it with a table alias:

```
SELECT att.e_id, att.date, 
(SELECT time FROM att a2 WHERE a2.e_id = att.e_id AND state = '0' ) as 'enter_time', 
(SELECT time FROM att a2 WHERE a2.e_id = att.e_id AND state = '1' ) as 'end_time' 
from att GROUP BY e_id, date
```

Output:

```
e_id    date        enter_time  end_time
1       2019-05-09  09:39:50    15:39:05
2       2019-05-09  08:39:50    16:39:05
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/phNjjecxKESdCENUgJPVDy/1)

You can do this more efficiently with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT att.e_id, att.date, 
MAX(CASE WHEN state = 0 THEN time END) as 'enter_time', 
MAX(CASE WHEN state = 1 THEN time END) as 'end_time' 
from att 
GROUP BY e_id, date;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/phNjjecxKESdCENUgJPVDy/2)

Comment: Thank you for this solution

Comment: @DardanGashi I've just edited with a *much* more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

No need for subqueries

please try this :

```
SELECT a.e_id, a.date, enter.time  as 'enter_time',endd.time as 'end_time'
  from att a,
       att enter,
       att endd
 where enter.state='0' 
   and endd.state='0' 
   and enter.e_id=a.e_id 
   and endd.e_id=a.e_id
   and a.state='0'  
 order by a.e_id, a.date
```

If you want to you use your query, please add state='0' in main query and fix aliases

```
SELECT b.e_id, b.date, 
(SELECT time FROM att a WHERE a.e_id = b.e_id AND a.state = '0' ) as 'enter_time', 
(SELECT time FROM att a WHERE a.e_id = b.e_id AND a.state = '1' ) as 'end_time' 
from att b where b.state='0'
```

Demo on SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7dcafb/14